# Eclipse CDT prettyprint broken

Tags: gdb, eclipse-cdt, pretty-print

I am using Ubuntu 13.10, Eclipse Kepler Service Release 1, GDB 7.6.1-ubuntu and latest CDT available through the Eclipse "install new software". I followed the instructions posted on several sites to set up prettyprinting for the STL containers.

Since it didn't work this way, following other instructions I modified the printers.py to have the len of strings maximized to 100 and formatted all raise ValueError, "..." to raise ValueError("...").

My .gdbinit file is the following:

```
python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/fbence/stlPrettyPrinter')
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
end
```

My settings are these:

http://fbence.web.elte.hu/setup.png

If I go to the debug button it has my configuration set as first, and it seems to use it too (otherwise I wouldn't had have to change the printers.py I think), but the debug as... is empty.

The gbd traces have messages like these:

193,677 36^error,msg="Could not get children iterator".

193,674 35^done,name="var5",numchild="0",value="{static npos = , _M_dataplus = {> = {<__\
gnu_cxx::new_allocator> = {}, }, _M_p = 0x0}}",type="std::stri\
ng",thread-id="1",displayhint="string",dynamic="1",has_more="0"

**This is the output:** http://fbence.web.elte.hu/eclipseproblem.png

Using gdb from the terminal results in the following output, when I want to print a simple vector:

```
Python Exception <class 'TypeError'> iter() returned non-iterator of type '_iterator':

$3 = std::vector of length 6, capacity 16
```

Obviously, my question is, how do I fix this? Without prettyprint I'd just rather debug under windows, but I don't really want to do that:)

Comment: Does pretty printing work in gdb command line without Eclipse?

Comment: I edited the question, short answer is no:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gdb libstdc++ pretty printers are actually broken in Ubuntu 13.10 now. See [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-4.8/+bug/1256419) for example.

gdb is linked with Python3 in Ubuntu 13.10, while pretty printers scripts support only Python2 syntax. You may apply [this patch](http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/287368/) to you pretty printers. It will add support of Python3. This solution worked for me though I don't use Eclipse for debugging.