# How to display the contents of a std::multimap and std::multiset in debugger in QtCreator?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, gdb, qt-creator

I am trying to inspect the contents of a `std::multimap` and `std::multiset` in the **Locals and Expressions** window of the **QtCreator**.

Instead of a list of values I get the implementation details displayed.

The strange thing is that the `std::map` and `std::set` counterparts are shown fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::multimap<int, std::string> multimap;
    multimap.insert(std::make_pair(1, "one"));
    multimap.insert(std::make_pair(2, "two"));
    multimap.insert(std::make_pair(3, "three"));

    std::multiset<int> multiset = {1,2,3};

    std::map<int, std::string> map;
    map.insert(std::make_pair(1, "one"));
    map.insert(std::make_pair(2, "two"));
    map.insert(std::make_pair(3, "three"));

    std::set<int> set = {1,2,3};

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

I am using:

```
Qt Creator 3.0.0 
gcc 4.8
GDB 7.6.1
Qt 5.2.0
Ubuntu 13.10
```

Is this feature supported?

Answer (score 1):

You might install the pretty printers for gdb:

- See https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport
- See also
  http://nikosams.blogspot.de/2009/10/gdb-qt-pretty-printers.html
- And https://github.com/ruediger/Boost-Pretty-Printer/wiki

Make sure you get at least version 6

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have problems setting it up. I chose the first option from https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport. I downloaded the scripts, created and modified ~/.gdbinit, but I get the same results. Which option do you use?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to installing Python libstdc++ printers from https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport you should also fix them for Ubuntu 13.10.

You should apply this patch http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/287368/ to make them work. See also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21020798/72178.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but it didn't work for me. I applied the patch and reloaded .gdbinit and now I have just <not accessible> in the "value field"